# pandas.rpy.common.load_data() usage/documentation?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, rpy2

I am trying to convert some `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.Matrix'>` variables into Pandas dataframes.

There is a lot of copy-paste instructions of how to do so on the internet, all giving the brief example:

```
pandas.rpy.common.load_data("infert")
```

without any information on where `"infert"` is coming from. 
I was unable to get any sort of documentation on this function (why is there none?), but apparently I cannot use it:

```
summary= r.summary(linear_model)
filtered_summary=summary.rx2("tTable")
print com.load_data("filtered_summary")
```

gives me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-a087eddd5220> in <module>()
      8 #print test1_sum.names
      9 print type(r_res)
---> 10 print com.load_data("filtered_summary")
     11 #print pd.DataFrame(test1_sum.rx2("tTable"))
     12 

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/rpy/common.pyc in load_data(name, package, convert)
     29     r.data(name)
     30 
---> 31     robj = r[name]
     32 
     33     if convert:

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.pyc in __getitem__(self, item)
    226 
    227     def __getitem__(self, item):
--> 228         res = _globalenv.get(item)
    229         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    230         res.__rname__ = item

LookupError: 'filtered_summary' not found
```

while:

```
summary= r.summary(linear_model)
print com.load_data("summary")
```

gives me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-b51722281aa4> in <module>()
      8 #print test1_sum.names
      9 print type(r_res)
---> 10 print com.load_data("summary")
     11 #print pd.DataFrame(test1_sum.rx2("tTable"))
     12 

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/rpy/common.pyc in load_data(name, package, convert)
     32 
     33     if convert:
---> 34         return convert_robj(robj)
     35     else:
     36         return robj

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/rpy/common.pyc in convert_robj(obj, use_pandas)
    222             return converter(obj)
    223 
--> 224     raise TypeError('Do not know what to do with %s object' % type(obj))
    225 
    226 

TypeError: Do not know what to do with <class 'rpy2.robjects.functions.SignatureTranslatedFunction'> object
```

So:

- How do I use `load_data` correctly
- How can I best get my R matrix converted to a Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load_data` function can be used to load datasets into a dataframe that are available in the R [`datasets`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) package, so it is a wrapper around the R [`data()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/data.html) function.

Eg:

```
from pandas.rpy.common import load_data
iris = load_data('iris')
```

will load the well-known iris dataset. It is mentioned briefly in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html#transferring-r-data-sets-into-python

If you want to convert a `rpy2.robjects...` you can do:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

and then conversion should happen automatically. Or you can do explicitly: `pandas2ri.ri2pandas(rpy2_object)`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether this is the "correct" use of load_data but I've found that if your R dataframe (say, myRData) is stored in the default workspace (.RData) in the default working directory then you can use load_data to load myRData using:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import pandas.rpy.common as com
print robjects.r.load(".RData")
myRData = com.load_data('myRData')
```

You could use robjects.r.XXX to run other R functions such as robjects.r.getwd() or robjects.r.setwd("path_to_new_working_directory") to navigate to new working directories.